# How to insert into the table a user name record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a table. In this table I have two columns - 'insert_name' and 'modified_name'. I need to insert into this columns data about who has inserted data into the table('insert_name') and who has changed these data in the table (modified_name). How it can be done?

[image]

Comment: Add some graphical representation or data to explain it.

Comment: I have added graphical representation

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for basic [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements.

If your record is already in the table, then you need to `UPDATE` it. Otherwise, when you are about to add your record to it and it doesn't already exist in the destination table then you are looking for `INSERT INTO` statement.

Example of updating information for record with first id:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET insert_name = 'value1', modified_name = 'value2' WHERE id = 1
```

Example of inserting new record:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable(id, company_name, product_name, insert_name) 
VALUES (1, 'Google', 'PC', 'value1')
```

If you are looking for automatic changes to those columns then you need to look into **triggers**.

---

Remember that more often than not you may find that the application connecting to the database is using single database user in which case you probably know the context within the application itself (who inserts, who updates). This does eliminate triggers and put the task straight on simple insert/update commands from within your application layer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the CURRENT_USER function to find the name of the user making the change.

The value from this function could then be used to update the appropriate column. This update could be done as part of the INSERT or UPDATE statement. Alternatively use an INSERT or UPDATE trigger.

Personally I avoid triggers if I can.

Answer (score 0):

For those 2 columns add Current_User as Default constraint.
As the first time Insert Statement will save them with current login user names. For update write an Update trigger with the same Current_User statement for the column Modified_Name.

If and only if your application business logic can't update the column modified_nme then only go for Trigger.

See the use of Current_Use 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050.aspx